# How to get horizontal center position of hslider in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

i want to user horizontal position of hslider instead of x position. so how to get horizontal center of any component in flex? please help me out.
thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where is the problem? [objectName.x + objectName.width/2]

Answer (score 0):

Very simple. get the width of the component and divide it by 2. You will get the horizontal center of the component.